# How to use SMS content provider? Where are the docs?

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider

I'd like to be able to read the system's SMS content provider. Basically I wanted to make an SMS messaging app, but it would only be useful if I could see past threads etc.

It seems like there's a content provider for this, but I can't find documentation for it - anyone know where that is?

Thanks

-------- edit -----------

Ok I found a way to get the sms inbox provider, and I just dumped all the column names in that provider, looks like this:

```
Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSms, null,null,null,null); 

// column names for above provider:
0: _id
1: thread_id
2: address
3: person
4: date
5: protocol
6: read   
7: status
8: type
9: reply_path_present
10: subject
11: body
12: service_center
13: locked
```

I'm just piecing this together from random threads I find around the net, I'm really wondering where this is all documented (if at all)?

Thanks again

Comment: the guys below pointed it out ( guess you don't like the answer though ). keep waiting for the api to become public :-)

Comment: Do anyone know the type of above mentioned columns?

Answer (score 8):

This is what I got from API 23:

```
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_THREAD_ID = "thread_id";
public static final String COLUMN_ADDRESS = "address";
public static final String COLUMN_PERSON = "person";
public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date";
public static final String COLUMN_DATE_SENT = "date_sent";
public static final String COLUMN_PROTOCOL = "protocol";
public static final String COLUMN_READ = "read";
public static final String COLUMN_STATUS = "status";
public static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "type";
public static final String COLUMN_REPLY_PATH_PRESENT = "reply_path_present";
public static final String COLUMN_SUBJECT = "subject";
public static final String COLUMN_BODY = "body";
public static final String COLUMN_SERVICE_CENTER = "service_center";
public static final String COLUMN_LOCKED = "locked";
public static final String COLUMN_ERROR_CODE = "error_code";
public static final String COLUMN_SEEN = "seen";
public static final String COLUMN_TIMED = "timed";
public static final String COLUMN_DELETED = "deleted";
public static final String COLUMN_SYNC_STATE = "sync_state";
public static final String COLUMN_MARKER = "marker";
public static final String COLUMN_SOURCE = "source";
public static final String COLUMN_BIND_ID = "bind_id";
public static final String COLUMN_MX_STATUS = "mx_status";
public static final String COLUMN_MX_ID = "mx_id";
public static final String COLUMN_OUT_TIME = "out_time";
public static final String COLUMN_ACCOUNT = "account";
public static final String COLUMN_SIM_ID = "sim_id";
public static final String COLUMN_BLOCK_TYPE = "block_type";
public static final String COLUMN_ADVANCED_SEEN = "advanced_seen";
public static final String COLUMN_B2C_TTL = "b2c_ttl";
public static final String COLUMN_B2C_NUMBERS = "b2c_numbers";
public static final String COLUMN_FAKE_CELL_TYPE = "fake_cell_type";
public static final String COLUMN_URL_RISKY_TYPE = "url_risky_type";
```

And this is how I print all the contents:

```
    private void readAllMessages() {
    List<Sms> smssList = new ArrayList<Sms>();
    Sms sms;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String message = "";
        do {
            sms = new Sms();
            sms.set_id(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_ID)));
            sms.setThreadId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_THREAD_ID)));
            sms.setAddress(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_ADDRESS)));
            sms.setPerson((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_PERSON))));
            sms.setDate((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_DATE))));
            sms.setDateSent((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_DATE_SENT))));
            sms.setProtocol((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_PROTOCOL))));
            sms.setRead((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_READ))));
            sms.setStatus((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_STATUS))));
            sms.setType((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_TYPE))));
            sms.setReplyPathPresent((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_REPLY_PATH_PRESENT))));
            sms.setSubject((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_SUBJECT))));
            sms.setBody((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_BODY))));
            sms.setServiceCenter((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_SERVICE_CENTER))));
            sms.setLocked((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_LOCKED))));
            sms.setErrorCode((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_ERROR_CODE))));
            sms.setSeen((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_SEEN))));
            sms.setTimed((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_TIMED))));
            sms.setDeleted((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_DELETED))));
            sms.setSyncState((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_SYNC_STATE))));
            sms.setMarker((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_MARKER))));
            sms.setSource((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_SOURCE))));
            sms.setBindId((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_BIND_ID))));
            sms.setMxStatus((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_MX_STATUS))));
            sms.setMxId((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_MX_ID))));
            sms.setOutTime((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_OUT_TIME))));
            sms.setAccount((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_ACCOUNT))));
            sms.setSimId((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_SIM_ID))));
            sms.setBlockType((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_BLOCK_TYPE))));
            sms.setAdvancedSeen((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_ADVANCED_SEEN))));
            sms.setB2cTtl((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_B2C_TTL))));
            sms.setB2cNumbers((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_B2C_NUMBERS))));
            sms.setFakeCellType((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_FAKE_CELL_TYPE))));
            sms.setUrlRiskyType((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_URL_RISKY_TYPE))));

            Log.v(TAG, "SMS read " + sms);
            smssList.add(sms);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "The user does not have any sms");
    }
}
```

The source code could be found here:
https://github.com/jiahaoliuliu/Akami/tree/feature/allSmsFields

Answer (score 7):

In addition to those u can see the list of fields in sms content provider by using following code:

```
private void displaySmsLog() {
    Uri allMessages = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
     //Cursor cursor = managedQuery(allMessages, null, null, null, null); Both are same
    Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(allMessages, null,
            null, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            Log.d(cursor.getColumnName(i) + "", cursor.getString(i) + "");
        }
        Log.d("One row finished",
                "**************************************************");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the content provider for Sms and Mms ([`android.providers.Telephony`](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=core/java/android/provider/Telephony.java;h=d8c5a53771a7af9f73273dd788db1fc3ed4f674e;hb=HEAD)) is not part of the [public API](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=api/current.xml;h=55d910508cca358fbe653fc2f50e66e40bc521fd;hb=6eccc390737a873d2334d628e1d06cc1857fcaee) at this moment. Until it is, you can define your own constants using [this](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=core/java/android/provider/Telephony.java;h=d8c5a53771a7af9f73273dd788db1fc3ed4f674e;hb=HEAD) as a template.

Comment: The links are not working anymore, can you update your answer plz?

Comment: [New link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/provider/Telephony.java) on `GrepCode`

Answer (score 5):

You can take a look a the new API 19 : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.html

Answer (score 3):

Use the selectionArgs field

```
String limite = "the timestamp converted to String";
Cursor cur = c.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null,"date" + ">?", new String[] {limite},null);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    String colName;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView tView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);

        ContentResolver cr =getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        //Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms"); -- For all SMS
        //Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"); -- For all Sent Items
        //If you want to read the Sent SMS then change the URi to /sent.

        //In this example we are using Query as we have defined URi as above.
        //We have declared all the Column names we need in string array in the second parameter.
        //If you dont need all then leave null
        //Notice that we did not call managedQuery instead we used Query method of ContentResolver
        Cursor messagesCursor = cr.query(uri, new String[] { "_id","address","body","person"}, null,null, null);
        colName = "ColumnName" +"\n";
        colName = colName +  "--------------" + "\n";

        for(int loopCounter=0; loopCounter < messagesCursor.getColumnCount() ; loopCounter++)
        {
            colName = colName + messagesCursor.getColumnName(loopCounter) + "\n";

        }
        colName = colName +  "--------------" + "\n";

        if(messagesCursor.getCount() > 0)
        {
            while(messagesCursor.moveToNext())
            {
                colName = colName +  messagesCursor.getString(messagesCursor.getColumnIndex("body")) + "--";
                colName = colName +  messagesCursor.getString(messagesCursor.getColumnIndex("address")) + "\n";
            }
        }
        tView.setText(colName);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do something like below:

```
for(String s : cursor.getColumnNames()){
     Log.d("smsColumns", "Column: " + s);
}
```