# how to add sms send and receive to call lomgs

Tags: android, sms, android-contacts

I am working on an android project. I am displaing all the incoming,outgoing and missed calls.
I want to also add the sms sent and receive. How can I do that? Is there a library that displays all the sms from the android phone?

Appreciate for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct library. You have to use a content provider (opened using an URI) and  fetch messages using it. Then create your own List with custom adapter and add SMS data into it.

Comment: is there an example you can give?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976252/how-to-use-sms-content-provider-where-are-the-docs) gives you an example and some discussion of how SMS content providers work.