# SMS: i reads only what is sent to me, How to read the entire conversation

Tags: android, sms

i have this code for read SMS

```
public List<String> getSMS(){
     List<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
        Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);

        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
               String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
               String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
              sms.add("Number: " + address + " .Message: " + body);  

          }
        return sms;

    }
```

It reads only what is sent to me,  How to read the entire conversation, Also what I sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query sent messages using the `content://sms/sent` URI. Also, try `content://sms/` to get all messages at once.

For more information refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13709207/198996

Comment: thank for the help, how to get the name of person that send the mail ? (if he in my phone-book) and how to sort by date and persone

Comment: @Gold You should post a new question for this to get answered. ;)